# Is their any difference between Sql server and Oracle

Tags: sql-server-2008, oracle10g

As i know about Both Sqlserver and Oracle are Database Systems.
1. In case of Sql server, we can work with multiple databases at once.

Is their any other difference between oracle and sql server.

Comment: Oracle can work with multiple instances at the same time.

Comment: The differences are huge, from supported operating systems, to differences in SQL syntax, to PL/SQL and T-SQL differences...

Comment: @darioo : In case of SQl server we can  execute Mysql,Tsql. right.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_databases) of databases, there are quite a few differences.

Answer (score 1):

They both store data, but apart from that they are like chalk and cheese - they are massively different in a lot of ways.

Oracle can be used as a small database system, but is more aimed at the enterprise data storage level, whereas SQL Server is more commonly used at the lower end of the data storage market (although they also have a very good enterprise level product).

I suggest you just start with the Wikipedia entries, then if you have more specific questions come back and ask them.

- [Oracle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database)
- [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)

P.S. Even though I tendered an answer, I'm voting to close this as the question is way too broad in scope.